# Table row highlighting

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

Been scouring the net for the 'best' way to do table row highlighting.

Seems that the two main alternatives are:

1 Pure CSS: `tr:hover`

2 Css + Jquery:

```
$("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
  if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
    $(this).parent().addClass("tr-hover");
  }
  else {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("tr-hover");
  }
});
```

I have no idea what is considered best practise these days. As far as I can ascertain, its only IE7 that doesn't work properly with the Pure CSS option.

Or, are there other alternatives that I should consider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the CSS [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3ahover) method. It does also work in IE7+, provided that a DOCTYPE is set. This statement is backed-up by [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/08/22/712830.aspx).

> ... improve CSS2.1 compliance.  All this work (with the exception of transparent PNGs) has been done **under the [<!DOCTYPE> switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dnie60/html/cssenhancements.asp) only**, since all changes required behavioral updates to be more in line what the CSS spec specifies.
>   
>   . . . 
>   We also extended our existing implementations to comply with W3C specifications:
>
> - Enable :hover on all elements not just on `<a>`

According to personal tests (and by [this source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250395.aspx#cssenhancements_topic2)), standards-compliant mode is **not activated** when:

- No DOCTYPE is set
  or when the DOCTYPE is set, and:
- A versionless HTML is specified.
- A HTML version lower than 4.x is specified (including non-existent lower versions, such as 3.99)
- HTML 4 is specified (instead of 4.x) without URL. `http://` is also valid, other protocols are invalid.
- HTML 4.x Transitional *or* HTML 4.x Frameset **without** an URL part.

It is activated with all other DOCTYPEs, including XHTML, XML, and unknown ones.

---

Pros for CSS:

- It's much more efficient than jQuery: no event listeners are involved, the behaviour is defined right after the definition of the CSS rule *(jQuery requires the library and a function call)*.
- It also works when JavaScript is disabled.

Pros for jQuery:

- It also works in IE6-
  (this markup is not that critical, so this would not have a big weight. Who is using IE6 by the way?).

Comment: Additionally, he could employ both, and only load the jQuery solution when the end-user is using IE7.

Comment: @crush But IE7 **does** support `:hover`, provided that the doctype is set. I lean towards `:hover`..

Comment: I just took the authors word for it. Who doesn't set the doctype!? Does it work with any doctype, so long as it is set? Only Strict? Only Transitional?

Good to know!

Comment: @crush I've updated my answer, to back-up my statement with sources and experience proofs.